# Am i using fastclick.js correctly?

Tags: javascript, fastclick.js

I want to see if i am using fastclick.js right. I can't really tell if its faster or not. Here is my code:

```
<script type='application/javascript' src='fastclick.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    new FastClick(document.body);
}, false);
    </script>
```

Comment: Belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The official sample: (https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
}, false);
```

Is just a synonym for what you do. As the actual code states that:

```
FastClick.attach = function(layer, options) {
    'use strict';
    return new FastClick(layer, options);
};
```

Anyway, you might want to consider carefully if FastClick is the suitable solution for you... It has a giant performance problem, because of the way it behaves (Computing hit tests. On large doms - that's an overkill)